# iframe dont display pdf with path from D:\ drive?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, iframe

I want to display pdf on iframe, but my pdf is not on the project folder(C:\intetpub\wwwroot). It was saved on drive D:\.

sample code:
`<iframe src="D:\Test.pdf#page=30"></iframe>`

i tried the ff:

```
src="file:///D:/Test.pdf#page=30"
src="<%: Url.Content(Model.path) %>"
```

but still no luck. I dont want to copy/move the pdf on project folder or root folder. Is there any other way to do this or my src path is wrong ?

I was planning to create a showPDF.aspx, put this on the iframe, but i'm afraid that adobe url parameter might not work wtih this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write a controller action that will retrieve the file and stream it back to the response:

```
public ActionResult Pdf()
{
    return File(@"d:\test.pdf", "application/pdf");
}
```

and now in your view you could use an iframe to point it to this controller action:

```
<iframe src="<%= Url.Action("Pdf", "SomeController") %>"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the code you have pasted, the browser will attempt to display that file from the CLIENT machine D drive.  You will need to create a virtual directory in your application which points to your PDF folder.  Then you can reference that virtual directory as you would an actual directory in your web application root.

1. Set a virtual directory in IIS  (called PDF maybe?) and point to D:\
2. Now, your source link could be something like `src="\PDF\Test.pdf"`

The other way would be to have a controller/action that goes to that directory, reads the file into a byte array and returns a `FileResult` with the content of the file to the end user.  [Here is an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905426/how-to-send-xml-file-to-client-in-asp-net-mvc) to how to return a file to a user from a controller action or returns the file directly as suggested by Darin

```
public ActionResult Pdf()
{
    return File(@"d:\test.pdf", "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: PDF action result is working,  i will try the virtual directiory for other option. thanks.